# Custom/Modified 'Fibonacci' Number sequence

Tags: javascript, arrays, fibonacci

I need to produce a much more different implementation of the Fibonacci sequence. Here is the implementation

```
(FSM) - FSM(0) = 0,
FSM(1) = 1, 
FSM(n) = FSM(n - 2) + FSM(n - 1) / n
```

How do I achieve this in javascript? I am supposed to feed in a large int `60000000` and get the next 10 numbers in the sequence.

Please note that there is a /n on the (n-1) part of the equation.

My current code looks like this:

```
var fibonacci = (function() {
        var memo = {};


          function f(n) {
            var value;


            if (n in memo) {
              value = memo[n];
            } else {
              if (n === 0 || n === 1)
                value = n;
              else             
              value = f(n - 1)/n + f(n - 2);
              memo[n] = value;
            }
            console.log(value);
            return value;
          }


          return f;
        })();
fibonacci(10);
```

Now my task says "Get the 10 following Modified Fibonacci Numbers starting from 60000000 element"

If I pass fibonacci(60000000); this will crash.

Comment: Do you have any Javascript knowledge? Have you made any attempts?

Comment: Yes I do. I am new to the whole Fibonacci principle on javascript and most of the tutorials online assume that you want a sequence from 0,1. That I can implement. I need someone to show me how to  start from (x)

Comment: See http://nayuki.eigenstate.org/page/fast-fibonacci-algorithms

Comment: @user3417202: If you are new to the Fibonacci principle then start with the basic implementations in JavaScript you saw until you understand the idea of it, then try to update them and then post [**your attempt**](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so we can help you fix it. Someone simply posting you a complete solution is not going to make it easier for you to understand.

Comment: My code is not the same, please note that there is a /n on the (n-1).

Comment: @FrançoisWahl the code snipped/instruction I have above is not the same. It's a modified version. I simply need to know how to pass the n parameter and start the computation at this point.

Comment: @user3417202: `I am supposed to feed in a large int 60000000 and get the next 10 numbers in the sequence`, Take any of the recursive JavaScript examples on the net and simply use the initial specified parameter to start instead of `0, 1`. Try that, and post your code when you are getting stuck.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl `60000000` is too large int, JavaScript can't handle it and I don't think that there is any other way to get info what OP wants than starting number checking from 0

Comment: And if we start from zero the recursion would simply crash. Right? So this can't work?

Comment: @crypticous: `60000000 is too large int, JavaScript can't handle it` not sure what you mean exactly, running it in [**one of my own samples**](http://jsfiddle.net/u4B4h/light/) I get quite large numbers returned and only after the result show `1.3069892237633987e+308` does it start going into `infinity`

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I meant that it needs too much time, probably browser crashes (on weak machines too), and like you see `infinity` isn't clear number :)

Comment: @crypticous: I still don't really know what OP wants. Is it 10 sequences after the number `60000000` or is it the 10 sequences following the `60000000`th sequence in the set? Not sure myself, hope your answer does hit the spot though :)

Comment: @FrançoisWahl OP wants 10 numbers (which belongs fibonacci numbers sequence) starting from the number which is greater than `60000000` :)

Comment: I don't think you can take the derivative of a sequence.  You might be able to take the integral, though...

Comment: Fib(n) has about 0.21*n decimal digits, for n=60,000,000 this results in 12,600,000 digits. This is several (screen or paper) hundred pages if printed out. Are you really sure this is the exact task description? On the other hand, 60,000,000 is between Fib(38) and Fib(39), which is still manageable.

Comment: Is the division by n intended to be integer or floating point division?

Comment: It is not indicated. I have improved on my code a bit. Let me share it.

Comment: The task states that "Get the 10 following Fibonacci Numbers starting from 60000000 element"

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

Try following one.
Parameters: `n` from where to start saving numbers, `m` how many numbers do you want to save

```
function getFibonacci(n,m) {
    var a = 0, b = 1, z = null, arr = [], c = 0;

    for ( var i = 0; i <= n; i++ ) {
        if ( a >= n ) {
            if ( c >= m ) {
                return arr;
            }
            arr.push(a);
            c++;
        }
        z = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = z;
    }
}

getFibonacci(60000000,10); // [63245986, 102334155, 165580141, 267914296, 433494437, 701408733, 1134903170, 1836311903, 2971215073, 4807526976]
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EbtH5/3/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the code sample.

Few queries:
How do I get the next sequence? `[60000000,*,*,*]`?

My code also has a division operand. I do not see that in your code.

Comment: @user3417202 In such a big numbers you can't use `JavaScript` for fibonacci sequence problems

Comment: @user3417202 I can't guessed what you mean. Did you see DEMO ? If you specify only `n` you will get boolean (true/false) based on number, if you input second parameter too you will get all the fibonacci numbers from `0` to `n`

Comment: @user3417202 Sure, it gives you `false` because you're only checking if number belongs or not to fibonacci sequence, though go ahead and try to get numbers to `200000000`

Comment: I am not seeing the division in your code. Please note that this is not the regular fibonacci series but a modification. There is a division operand in my code. How do I accomplish that with your a+b sample codes?

Comment: @user3417202 I can't guess what you want, I wrote what you question demanded

Comment: Look at my code. I have `f(n - 1)/n + f(n - 2);`

That is missing from your code sample.

Comment: @user3417202 Listen you me, what do you want eventually, I wrote script which accomplishes your request, is not it ? I am not going to start thinking the way you're doing in your code. If you don't like something, don't get on my nerves and don't post anything to me, go and ask question again.

Comment: Am saying your code does not have the division that is in my custom function. That is what I have been trying to say ever since you wrote the code. What you have me is the 'normal' fib function. Mine has a division operand. That is not taken care of in your code. How does that work?

Have a look at my code and key in: fib(60000000)